# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE `dailydata` (
  `id`         int(9)         NOT NULL,
  `Date`       varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
  `EmpID`      varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
  `name`       varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
  `TeamName`   varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
  `active`     varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
  `idle`       double         NOT NULL,
  `Stime`      double         NOT NULL,
  `Etime`      varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
  `Inofficehr` decimal(20,2)  NOT NULL,
  `activehr`   double(19,2)   NOT NULL,
  `idlehr`     double(19,2)   NOT NULL,
  `Timestamp`  timestamp      NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Set Primary key For 'id' column:

```
ALTER TABLE `dailydata`ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Now I'm trying to insert the data with this code:

```
INSERT INTO dailydata 
SELECT A.Date, A.EmpID, B.name, B.TeamName, 
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'active' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS active,
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'idle' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS idle,
Min(A.Statestarttime) AS Stime, MAX(A.StateEndtime) AS Etime,
ROUND((TIME_TO_SEC(MAX(A.StateEndtime))/60 - 
TIME_TO_SEC(MIN(A.StateStarttime))/60)/60,2) as Inofficehr, 
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'active' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END)/60,2) 
AS activehr, 
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'idle' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END)/60,2) 
AS idlehr 
FROM time A join ttld.login B on A.EmpID=B.username 
WHERE A.Date='01-01-2019' AND A.Statestarttime <>'' AND A.StateEndtime <>'' 
GROUP BY A.EmpID;
```

But I'm getting this error:

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I understand I have not define the ID in my insert code and the reason for it is I want it to auto populate.

How can I modify my `INSERT` query code to do so...

Comment: Add `AUTO_INCREMENT` to your `id` column and include the primary key definition in `CREATE TABLE` or assign a value to `id` in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `dailydata` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`); will this not work do i need to create new table?

this method working in other table i want to understand why this is not working in this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 13 columns in your table, but only 11 in your select, which is why you are getting this error.

But first, to make your `id` column auto-populate, you need to declare it as `AUTO_INCREMENT`. You can change it with an [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) command:

```
ALTER TABLE dailydata CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Since you have a default value for your `Timestamp` column you don't need to insert a value for that.

To resolve the error you are seeing, you need to modify your `INSERT` query to to match the number of columns being inserted to the data either by
 (a) naming the columns you are inserting; or
 (b) inserting `NULL` values for the columns with no values (`id` and `Timestamp`)

e.g. (a)

```
INSERT INTO dailydata (`Date`, `EmpID`, `name`, `TeamName`, `active`, `idle` ,`Stime`, `Etime`, `Inofficehr`, `activehr`, `idlehr`)
SELECT A.Date, A.EmpID, B.name, B.TeamName, 
...
```

e.g. (b)

```
INSERT INTO dailydata
SELECT NULL AS id,
A.Date, A.EmpID, B.name, B.TeamName,
...
NULL AS Timestamp
FROM ...
```