# I want a electricity billing system using python and Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, system, billing

I am a beginner in Python and MySQL and I am trying to make an electricity billing system where I want python to give three options 1. New user,2. existing use 3. exit and Mysql should create its table when the user enters his choice. But in my code when i enter my choice it shows error.

```
**import mysql.connector as sql , random , datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
conn=sql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='mc.la.ren',database='EBS')
if conn.is_connected():
    print("successfully connected")
c='YES' or "yes" or 'Yes'
V='YES' or "yes" or 'Yes'
c1=conn.cursor() 
while c=='YES' or "yes" or 'Yes':
    print('************************WELCOME TO ELECTRICITY BILLING SYSTEM************************')
    print(dt.datetime.now())
    print('1.NEW USER')
    print('2.EXISTING USER')
    print('3.EXIT')
    choice1=int(input('ENTER YOUR CHOICE:'))
    if choice1==1:
        username=input("Enter your username number :")
        password=input("Enter your password:")
        confirmpasswd=input("Confirm  your password:")
        if password==confirmpasswd:
            info1="insert into newuser values('{}','{}','{}')".format(username,password,confirmpasswd)
            c1.execute(info1)
            conn.commit()
            c=input("do you want to continue?(yes or no)")
        else:
            print('your confirm password is incorrect')
            print('Try again')
            c=input("do you want to continue?(yes or no)")
    elif choice1==2:
        username=input('Enter your username:')
        password=input('Enter your password:')
        info2="select * from newuser where username='{}' and password='{}'".format(username,password)
        c1.execute(info2)
        data=c1.fetchall()
        while V=='YES' or "yes" or 'Yes':
            if any(data):
                print('************************WELCOME TO ELECTRICITY BILLING SYSTEM************************')
                print("1.ACCOUNT SETTINGS")
                print("2.TRANSACTION")
                print("3.VIEW CUSTOMER DETAILS")
                print("4.GRAPHICAL REPRESENTATION")
                print('5.EXIT')
                choice2=int(input('ENTER YOUR CHOICE'))
                if choice2==1:
                    print('1.NEW CUSTOMER')
                    print('2.DELETE EXISTING ACCOUNT')
                    choice12=int(input('ENTER YOUR CHOICE:'))
                    if choice12==1:
                        accountno=random.randrange(1000000,9999999,10)
                        print("your accountno is",accountno)
                        boxid=input("enter your mete box ID:")
                        bankname=input('Enter your BANK NAME  :')
                        bankbranch=input('Enter your BANK BRANCH  :')
                        name=input('Enter your name  :')
                        address=input('Enter your address  :')
                        areacode=int(input('Enter your area PIN CODE  :'))
                        phoneno=int(input('Enter your PHONE NUMBER  :'))
                        email=input('Enter your email  :')
                        info2="insert into AddNewCustomer values({},'{}','{}','{}','{}',{},{},'{}','{}')".format(accountno,bankname,bankbranch,name,address,areacode,phoneno,email,boxid)
                        c1.execute(info2)
                        conn.commit()
                        V=input("do you want to continue?(yes or no)")
                        if V=='yes':
                            continue
                        else:
                            break
                    elif choice12==2:
                        acc=input("ENTER YOUR ACCOUNT NUMBER:")
                        use=input("ENTER YOUR USERNAME:")
                        info6=c1.execute("delete from Transaction where accountno='{}'".format(acc))
                        info7=c1.execute("delete from AddNewCustomer where accountno='{}'".format(acc))
                        info8=c1.execute("delete from newuser where username='{}'".format(use))
                        c1.execute(info6)
                        c1.execute(info7)
                        c1.execute(info8)
                        conn.commit()
                        print("THANK YOU FOR USING OUR SOFTWARE,YOUR ACCOUNT IS SUCCESFULLY DELETED")
                        V=input("do you want to continue?(yes or no)")
                        if V=='yes':
                            continue
                        else:
                            break
                    
                elif choice2==2:
                    accountno=int(input('Enter your account number  :'))
                    info10="select * from Transaction where accountno="+str(accountno)
                    c1.execute(info10)
                    data3=c1.fetchall()
                    for row in data3:
                        paid=row[6]
                    if paid=='yes':
                        print('you have already paid the bill')
                        break
                    else:
                        unit=random.randint(0,101)
                        print('Dear customer, you have used ',unit,'units of electricity.')
                        print('One unit of curent is 150 ruppees')
                        amount=150*unit
                        toda=dt.date.today()
                        deadline=dt.date(2020,1,30)
                        if deadline<toda:
                            fine=(toda-deadline)*30
                            totamt=amount+fine
                            print('you have dealyed for ',toda-deadline,'days.The fine per day is 30 rupees.')
                            GST=(15/100)*totamt
                            totalamt=totamt+GST
                            print('Pleae payup ',totalamt,'rupees inclding GST')
                            p=input("Please Enter YES to transact")
                            if p=="YES"or 'Yes'or'yes':
                                print("Transaction successful")
                                print("You have paid the bill")
                            else:
                                print('plz pay the bill sooner')
                        else:
                            totamt=0
                            GST=(15/100)*amount
                            totalamt=amount+GST
                            print('Pleae payup ',totalamt,'rupees inclding GST')
                            p=input("Please Enter YES to transact")
                            if p=="YES":
                                print("Transaction successful")
                                print("You have paid the bill")
                            else:
                                print('plz pay the bill sooner')
                        info3="insert into Transaction values({},{},'{}',{},{},{},'{}')".format(accountno,unit,toda,totamt,GST,totalamt,p)
                        c1.execute(info3)
                        conn.commit()
                        V=input("do you want to continue?(yes or no)")
                        if V=='yes':
                            continue
                        else:
                            break
                elif choice2==3:
            
                    accountno=int(input('Enter your account number  :'))
                    info4="select * from AddNewCustomer where accountno=" + str(accountno)
                    c1.execute(info4)
                    data1=c1.fetchall()
                    for row in data1:
                        print(" Account Number: ", row[0])
                        print("bankname:",row[1])
                        print("bankbranch:",row[2])
                        print("Person name:",row[3])
                        print("Your meter device ID=",row[8])
                        print("Residential address:",row[4])
                        print("area code:",row[5])
                        print("phone number:",row[6])
                        print("email:",row[7])
                        info5="select * from Transaction where accountno=" + str(accountno)
                        c1.execute(info5)
                        data2=c1.fetchall()
                    for row in data2:
                
                        print(" Unit : ",row[1])
                        print(" paid on:",row[2])
                        print("amount to be paid without GST:",row[3])
                        print("GST=",row[4])
                        print("amount to be paid including GST:",row[5])
                    V=input("do you want to continue?(yes or no)")
                    if V=='yes':
                        continue
                    else:
                        break
                elif choice2==4:
                    info9="select accountno,totalamt from Transaction"
                    c1.execute(info9)
                    L1,L2,=[],[]
                    for i in c1.fetchall():
                        L1.append(i[0])
                        L2.append(i[1])
                    plt.plot(L1,L2)
                    plt.title("GRAPH")
                    plt.show()
                    V=input("do you want to continue?(yes or no)")
                    if V=='yes':
                        continue
                    else:
                        break
                elif choice2==5:
                    print("THANK  YOU!!!!  VISIT AGAIN!!!!")
                    break
                    c='yes'

          
            else:
                print('username / password is incorrect')
                break
                c=input("do you want to try again?(yes or no)")
            
                    
        else:
            print("THANK  YOU!!!!  VISIT AGAIN!!!!")
            V='no'
            
    

    elif choice1==3:
        print("THANK  YOU!!!!  VISIT AGAIN!!!!")
        c='no'
        break        
    else:
        print("invalid choice")
        c=input("do you want to try again?(yes or no)")
else:
    print("THANK  YOU!!!!  VISIT AGAIN!!!!")
    
    c='no'**
```

OUTPUT

```
successfully connected
************************WELCOME TO ELECTRICITY BILLING SYSTEM************************
2022-02-10 12:22:23.390606
1.NEW USER
2.EXISTING USER
3.EXIT
ENTER YOUR CHOICE:1
Enter your username number :1
Enter your password:1
Confirm  your password:1
```

It shows error `(1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1)` at last what should i do to fix it, and if i fix one error it shows another error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157330/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1-in-mysql